# how to use SQL wildcard % with Queryset extra>select?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I'm using the extra() modifier in a view.

(See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none )

Here's the the code:

```
def viewname(request)
    ...
    exact_matchstrings=[]
    exact_matchstrings.append("(accountprofile.first_name LIKE '" + term + "')")
    exact_matchstrings.append("(accountprofile.first_name LIKE '" + term + '\%' +  "')")

    extraquerystring = " + ".join(exact_matchstrings)

    return_queryset = return_queryset.extra(
        select = { 'match_weight': extraquerystring },
        )
```

The two append statements above are almost completely alike except that the second adds a `%` SQL wildcard character.  This is causing an error; the statement without the `%` causes no problems.  What's going on with the `%`?  I'm surprised that django thinks this character is not defined, since it's in SQL specification.  For example, the following SQL statement executes just fine:

```
select (first_name like "Car") + (first_name like "Car%") from accountprofile;
```

But trying to run it via the extra() modifier in my view code and evaluating the resulting queryset gives me an error.  I think "%" needs to be escaped, so I tried that already.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue ourselves doing a extra query with LIKE.  To escape a `%` you need to do `%%`

[Percentage sign not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976535/percentage-sign-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some quotes from the 2nd string.  And I'm not sure that you need to escape the percent (%) unless this is required by django.

```
_matchstrings.append("(accountprofile.first_name LIKE '" + term + "%" +  "')")
```