# Percentage sign not working

Tags: python, html

I am working with a HTML application with Python. I usually use the `%` sign to indicate that I'm using a Python element, and never had a problem with that before.

Now, I am using some tables which I'm trying to control their size bye the percentage using the `%` sign. So now the Python does not show the Python elements.

Here is some code to explain myself:

```
<table width="90%">
<tr>
<td width="60%">HELLO</td>
<td width="40%">GOOD BYE</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="BUTTON" onclick="function(%s)" /> ''' % variable
```

The error that I am having says

> unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 19"

making reference to the `%s` string in the `onclick=function(%s)`

Does someone know if the `%` sign in the tables affects Python or something like that?

Comment: Could you show the specific code that's giving the problem and expected output?

Comment: Would you please provide more information about your problem?  We don't know anything relevant yet.

Comment: Thanks! I ve already put some code to explain myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape '%' as '%%' in python strings. The error message you're getting probably is about the other percent signs. If you put only single percent sign in a string python thinks it will be followed by a format character and will try to do a variable substitution there.

In your case you should have:

```
'''

....
<table width="90%%">
<tr>
<td width="60%%">HELLO</td>
<td width="40%%">GOOD BYE</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="BUTTON" onclick="function(%s)" /> ''' % variable
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood you! How exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

In the newer Python (e.g., 2.6 or later), you can use `.format()` method. You will not need to escape your percent signs then:

```
s = '''<table width="90%">                                                                                
<tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<td width="60%">HELLO</td>                                                                                                                                                                                         
<td width="40%">GOOD BYE</td>                                                                                                                                                                                      
</tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
</table>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 <input type="button" value="BUTTON" onclick="function({funcarg})" /> '''

s.format(**{'funcarg': 'return'})
```