# python script to create fdf

Tags: python, string, fdf

I'm writing a python script to create an fdf file.  The first 2 lines of fdf file require the following:

```
%FDF-1.2
%‚„œ”
```

How can I write the symbols required in those two lines as a string?  When I create a new line, (e.g. `line_1 = "%FDF-1.2"`) I get an error because of the % symbol.  I need python to read it as text and not a command symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A '%' must be escaped as '%%'. Otherweise it acts as placeholder for string interpolation.

Related:

- [How can I selectively escape percent (%) in Python strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/selectively-escape-percent-in-python)
- [Percentage sign not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976535/percentage-sign-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, any advice for the comma in line 2?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a workaround.  Instead, I am now just copying the format that is created by exporting the data from the pdf I'm trying to write.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a the raw string notation

```
>>> a = r'%test'
>>> print a
%test
```